# DNS resolution failed: server IP address could not be found

Tags: linux, dns, hosts

/etc/hosts file has an entry in my development server `10.xx.xx.162 server-dev.xxx-intra.net`. `ping` to server-dev.xxx-intra.net is successful.But when I am trying to access from the browser - https://server-dev.xxx-intra.net, it throws `server-dev.xxx-intra.net's server IP address could not be found`. I understand that it is not able to resolve that name to IP but shouldn't /etc/hosts entry have taken care of this? Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: it doesn't work from any of the browsers

Comment: Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212897/nslookup-dig-firefox-ignoring-etc-hosts-file-entries

Comment: nothing works :(

Comment: What if you try http instead of https ?

Comment: if I try with IP + https, it works, although it shows 'not secure' since common name given was - server-dev.xxx-intra.net

Comment: Off topic for here - try on [su] or [sf]. But... if your in a work env does your system use a proxy server anywhere? that's usually a good thing to check first if you can ping the dev server and other protocols work (ssh/ftp etc)